Multiresolution for vertex group (blender 4.1)
Is it possible to generate (or simulate) multiresolution for only one vertex group (or mask)? The point is I need more geometry in a small part of the mesh (human model, subdividing the entire geometry doesn't seem reasonable). Is there a simpler way than manually re-topologizing the necessary part of the mesh? Probably the geometry nodes, if it will not ruin the armature/topology/uv/materials/etc.

Okay, I found some solution. I duplicated and separated the necessary part of the mesh, increased the multires level, sculpted the details. Then, I applied the multires. Than render properties -> bake -> bake type - normal -> space - object. This exports normals as a texture to the image connected in the material nodes. While the UV maps are similar in both objects, the image texture fits the base object as well. And I was able to import this image texture as a base for the normal map node. These actions worked for me, but I had to play with it for a while.
UPD: Ah, and I had to mix shaders by created mask, so the normals of the base object doesn't distort.
